# pandas groupby performance / combine 2 functions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, performance, pandas-groupby

I am learning python and trying to understand the best practices of data queries.
Here is some dummy data (*customer sales*) to test

```
import pandas as pd
 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['tom', 'bob', 'bob', 'jack', 'jack', 'jack'],'Amount':[3, 2, 5, 1, 10, 100], 'Date':["01.02.2022", "02.02.2022", "03.02.2022", "01.02.2022", "03.02.2022", "05.02.2022"]}) 
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%d.%m.%Y')
```

I want to investigate 2 kinds of queries:

1. How long is a person our customer?
2. What is the period between first
   and last purchase.

How can I run the first query without writing loops manually?

What I have done so far for the second part is this

```
result = df.groupby("Name").max() - df.groupby("Name").min()
```

**Is it possible to combine these two `groupby` queries into one to improve the performance?**

P.S. I am trying to understand `pandas` and key concepts how to optimize queries. Different approaches and explanations are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with a custom function to get the difference between the max and min date.

```
df.groupby('Name')['Date'].agg(lambda x: x.max()-x.min())
```

As you already have datetime type, this will nicely yield a Timedelta object, which by default is shown as a string in the form 'x days'.

You can also save the `GroupBy` object in a variable and reuse it. This way, computation of the groups occurs only once:

```
g = df.groupby("Name")['Date']
g.max() - g.min()
```

output:

```
Name
bob    1 days
jack   4 days
tom    0 days
Name: Date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you! Saving the groupby object does the trick! 

2 more questions: 1. What if I want to add a condition on Amount column? 2. Is it the best performance or we can do it faster somehow?

Comment: Depends what is your condition. For instance of you want to filter out low amounts, you can do it before the groupby. You can also mask values. You would need to explain exactly what you want. Regarding performance, this is probably the best that you can achieve with pandas.

Comment: Thank you, it seems that I overthink about the groupby method.